# Infinite series involving e

Tags: summation, exponential-function

Consider:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^x}{n!}$$
When $x$ is a whole number f(x) is also a whole number. Is there a way to resolve this summation?

Comment: You're sure it's $n^x$ in the numerator and not $x^n$, right?

Comment: $f(x)$ represents the $x^{th}$ Bell number via Dobinski's formula. A search for the Bell numbers and related will provide further information.

Comment: As suggested by Leucippus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula

Comment: It looks similar, but the mention of Bell numbers is what the answer I wanted. The other question had a different answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method of examination is to obtain a generating function. For this is can be determined that:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) \, \frac{t^n}{n!} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{n!} \, \frac{1}{e} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^{n}}{k!} \\
&= \frac{1}{e} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(k t)^{n}}{n!} \\
&= \frac{1}{e} \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{k t}}{k!} \\
&= e^{e^{t} - 1}.
\end{align}
This is the generating function for the Bell numbers, $B_{n}$. This implies that $f(n) = B_{n}$.